# Deploying OpenStack from source

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I have successfully deployed Openstack using Juju charms on a local ESXi VM setup using following command:
**juju quickstart openstack-base/36**

Now, I am trying to deploy the the openstack from source(https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/06/17/deploying-openstack-from-source-to-scalable-multi-node-environments/).

I downloaded all the yaml files into root directory and executed the following command

**juju-quickstart -n next.yaml --no-browser**

but Openstack did not get deployed. What am I missing? What are the correct steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folloing command deploys the openstack

**juju-deployer -d -c default.yaml -d trusty-liberty**